# Backend CRUD calls in python using Flask, Connexion, and SQLAlchemy

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

Backend CRUD calls in python using Flask, Connexion, and SQLAlchemy

I'm building a python app using REST APIs With Flask, Connexion, and SQLAlchemy as detailed in the great 3-parts tutorial at: https://realpython.com/flask-connexion-rest-api-part-3/
In this tutorial, there are classes defined as on ORM representations of the db tables (e.g. Person) within a model.py module:

```
# models.py

from datetime import datetime
from config import db, ma

class Person(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "person"
    person_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    lname = db.Column(db.String(32), unique=True)
    fname = db.Column(db.String(32))
    timestamp = db.Column(
        db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow, onupdate=datetime.utcnow
    )
# ...
```

In addition, a dedicated module is added for each table (e.g. people.py) with implementation of api calls that calls methods of Person:

```
from flask import abort, make_response

from config import db
from models import Person, people_schema, person_schema


def read_all():
    people = Person.query.all()
    return people_schema.dump(people)


def create(person):
    lname = person.get("lname")
    existing_person = Person.query.filter(Person.lname == lname).one_or_none()

    if existing_person is None:
        new_person = person_schema.load(person, session=db.session)
        db.session.add(new_person)
        db.session.commit()
        return person_schema.dump(new_person), 201
    else:
        abort(406, f"Person with last name {lname} already exists")
# ...
```

My question now is what should be the best way to access various CRUD operations and generally speaking, extending code to other methods while those should be accessed from within the backend as part of logic I develop?

My intuition was to add relevant methods to models.py and to import and call them but I found out that while create works perfectly, update calls seem to have no effect on db.
The example code of my update function is:

```
    def update(self, **kwargs) -> None:
        with app.app_context():
            for key, value in kwargs.items():
                setattr(self, key, value)
            db.session.commit()
```

I'll really appreciate your insights and comments!